# slimming unused std::stringstream locale/facets for embedded use?

Tags: c++, embedded, c++14, std, code-size

I'm currently building an application for a lowish-spec ARM Cortex M4 in C++, using `arm-none-eabi-g++` with stdlibc++ statically linked.

Some parts of the code are currently using `std::stringstream` to construct a string for various purposes, and would be quite difficult to remove/refactor out of the codebase.

A fairly basic subset of the code with all stringstreams shimmed

(via a `fakestream.h` header something like:

```
namespace blah {
    class stringstream {
        stringstream() {}
        ~stringstream() {}
        std::string str() {
           return "dummy";
        }
        template<typename T>
        stringstream& operator<<(T val) {
           return *this;
        }
    };
}
```

Along with invocations changed to:

```
#include "fakestream.h"
using blah::stringstream;
...
stringstream ss; 
ss << ...
```

trims about 350kB of code from the application, vs using std::stringstream.

I realise that some amount of that code is indeed necessary, but when using
[bloaty](https://github.com/google/bloaty) to inspect the .elf generated,
a lot of the space seems to be taken with functions such as:

```
     6.5%  20.0Ki    std::num_get<>::_M_extract_int<>()
     3.7%  11.3Ki    std::__cxx11::money_get<>::_M_extract<>()
     2.9%  8.97Ki    std::money_get<>::_M_extract<>()
     2.7%  8.24Ki    d_print_comp_inner
     2.3%  6.97Ki    _svfprintf_r
     2.1%  6.42Ki    _svfwprintf_r
     2.0%  6.11Ki    __strftime.isra.0
     2.0%  6.09Ki    __ssvfscanf_r
     1.8%  5.61Ki    __ssvfiscanf_r
     1.8%  5.54Ki    std::__cxx11::time_get<>::_M_extract_via_format()
     1.5%  4.65Ki    std::num_get<>::_M_extract_float()
     1.4%  4.29Ki    std::__cxx11::money_put<>::_M_insert<>()
     1.4%  4.24Ki    std::num_get<>::do_get()
     1.4%  4.17Ki    std::__moneypunct_cache<>::_M_cache()
     1.3%  3.96Ki    _strtod_l
     1.3%  3.89Ki    _vfiprintf_r
     1.3%  3.87Ki    std::time_get<>::_M_extract_via_format()
     1.2%  3.81Ki    _dtoa_r
     1.2%  3.64Ki    std::money_put<>::_M_insert<>()
     1.1%  3.53Ki    std::locale::_Impl::_Impl()
     1.1%  3.28Ki    std::__facet_shims::__moneypunct_fill_cache<>()
     1.1%  3.27Ki    _svfiprintf_r
     1.0%  3.21Ki    std::num_put<>::_M_insert_int<>()
     0.8%  2.54Ki    std::num_put<>::_M_insert_float<>()
     0.7%  2.11Ki    d_type
     0.6%  1.94Ki    std::__cxx11::time_get<>::_M_extract_name()
```

and I know for certain that I'm not using any `money` or `time` related classes/values for stringstream or anywhere else.

From what (little) I understand, there's potentially some locale-related indirection happening in `ios` or `ios_base` to allow these types to be formatted according to the active locale, but I have no need for any of that in this application.

Is it possible to somehow indicate that these features are unnecessary, and should be omitted from the final output?

Ideally it would be possible to just continue using `std::stringstream` directly, but replacing it with a proxy or similar as above (but that actually delegates the necessary functionality for formatting basic integer types, strings, and a few custom object overloads).

Comment: Do you enable compiler optimizations?

Comment: I don't know if using the `fmt` library, instead of `stringstream`s would be feasible for this case. If it is, it would be worth a try.

Comment: I've tried with `-O0`, `-Og`, and `-Os` optimisations in G++. It makes a (fairly small) difference to the overall binary size, but I think that's mostly in my code rather than the library code, which bloaty still shows as being present, and exactly the same size (as I'd kind of expect, if it's not recompiling the libstdc++ libraries each time they won't be affected by optimisation level - although maybe templates would expand differently? I don't really know)

Comment: I haven't seriously compared `{fmt}` - I did get it working briefly some time ago with the project, but it would be quite a job to convert all the uses of stringstream, and probably rewrite teh custom object formatter (well, `operator<<()` overloads) as well. Even if I did switch to fmt for formatting, I'd still probably want something to collect conditional fragments to assemble the final string - maybe std:;stringbuffer would serve for that?

Comment: "trims about 350kB of code from the application"  ...and then some people wonder why they should ban the use of C++ in embedded systems. What _are_ you using stringstream for, string formatting and hex coversions etc? Because something like that should take up around 1-2kb of code tops on your average Cortex M.

Comment: @Lundin probably nothing that it's necessary for really, but there's a lot of it throughout the codebase so it'd be a pain to change, short of switching out for a custom implementation that duplicates the stringstream interface (at least for the types we do use). Mostly it's concatting strings, char*'s, ints of various flavours to hex, zero-padded forms, etc for logging, and some custom-ish file format generation.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like a PC program using heap allocation. Cheap PC programmers means expensive BoM. Which might be a perfectly sound management approach for low-volume products.

Comment: @Lundin not C++'s fault, but the library - much of that should indeed be avoided for sure.  Problem comes from practitioners not knowing the difference or the cost.  You can if course prevent accidents by taking the sharp and complicated tools out if the tool bag!

Comment: GNU stdlibc++ in particular is not intend for embedded use.  If it is including unused code in the link, it sounds like you need to enable LTO perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford I haven't actually tried LTO now that you mention it. I'm using `-ffunction-sections` and data-sections, and linking with `--gc-sections`, but maybe that's not enough (especially if libstdc++ wasn't necessarily built with those options?) I'm somewhat of a novice at C++ and was warned away from LTO for its potential to hinder debuggability, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Clifford If there's one thing experience shows from badly written C or C++ projects, it is: _if a feature is available, someone will use it sooner or later_. In either language you have to restrict the language down to a safe subset. In the case of C++ it means removing around 90% of the available language features.

Comment: @Lundin any recommendations for style guides/coding standards that outline which 10% to use for embedded? Ideally with a rationale associated.

Comment: @Shabble There's MISRA C++ and the JSF standard but they are completely focusing on avoiding dangerous parts of the language rather than efficiency (although the dangerous parts _are_ probably around 90% of the language...). As for a rationale regarding why C++ should be used in embedded systems, I don't think it is possible to provide one. Bjarne Stroustrup made some relatively reasonable attempt at one point, I used to have a Powerpoint of it but I can't find it...

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, I meant more like rationale for the specific rules/guidelines within a style guide, rather than the "thou shalt not trigraph in mine sight" versions I've occasionally found when searching. I've seen the MISRA and AutoSAR ones, but still looking for other references that are maybe a little more permissive but still useful in avoiding some of the really dangerous footguns.

Comment: I don't know of any such sensible material, no. There was once a subset (of C++98) called [EC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B) and I even used that in one product (when I was young and naive enough to still use C++). However, C++ has changed a lot since then and not for the better.

Comment: Here's the best rationale I can give: ISO C 9899:2018 has a 20 pages long fine print list _briefly_ summarizing all forms of explicitly poorly-defined behavior in the standard. C++ has no such list, likely because the summary would be a book about as thick as ISO 14882 itself. I'm not sure if there even was an attempt to assemble such a list. If you find that list, then that's your best rationale ever for not using C++ (in embedded systems).

Comment: Someone made the attempt [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1705r1.html). Far as I can tell the committee is still scratching their heads about it. Maybe for C++23?

Comment: @Shabble Are you aware of the ["Embedded Template Library" (ETL)](https://www.etlcpp.com/home.html)? I never used it personally, but it does have a [stringstream](https://www.etlcpp.com/string_stream.html). Also, maybe [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html) performs better; they do at least mention embedded environments in the documentation.